# How can I tell if a thread was created by CreateRemoteThread?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Intuition tells me there's some way to look in the stack on a Windows thread and know whether the given thread was started via CreateRemoteThread or CreateThread.

Is my intuition anywhere near correct? Is there a way to know?

The motivation for this question is that I am looking at minidumps of crashes, seeing threads with a thread start address in RWX virtual memory, indicating dll injection via CreateRemoteThread. This is one thing I'd love to confirm.

Comment: Implementation details are often specific to an OS release. Which OS version did you use to pull the minidumps?

Comment: This is Windows 7 x86, though of course the most generalized solution would be best

Comment: no way to know. no difference in stack. your intuition wrong here

Comment: Typical DLL injection with `CreateRemoteThread()` simply uses `kernel32.LoadLibrary()` as the thread procedure (passing it an input parameter that is a pointer to a pathname allocated with `VirtualAllocEx()` and filled with `WriteProcessMemory()`), so your statement that you are "*seeing threads with a thread start address in RWX virtual memory*" doesn't make much sense to me.  Creating a remote thread with a dynamically allocated thunk as the thread procedure is difficult and not very useful for DLL injection.

Comment: No, most dll injection uses writeprocessmemory, then createremotethread in the memory written. A thread start address in LoadLibrary makes little sense because of the dangers of creating threads in DllMain

Comment: @tenfour: Most common DLL injections use `CreateRemoteThread()` to call `LoadLibrary()` directly, thus calling the DLL's entry point within the target process. `WriteProcessMemory()` is used to simply pass the DLL filename to `LoadLibrary()`. See [Using CreateRemoteThread for DLL Injection on Windows](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/) for details. This is the most common way to inject a DLL, but there are other ways.

Comment: Right. Very few people do that though because when your dll is loaded you risk a race condition by calling CreateThread from DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. This is from observation. Of course both methods would be ideal to handle but right now i only care about the most common cases.

Comment: For the record, there is no such race condition.  I know what the documentation says, but it is wrong in that respect.  (Of course that doesn't necessarily mean that people aren't choosing to do things the hard way because they *think* there is a race condition.)

Comment: First, a race conditions is the *exact opposite* of a deadlock. [Second, `CreateThread()` doesn't return once it knows that the thread has already started running; it returns once it sets up the thread and marks it as running/runnable, and the thread is free to start actually running at a later point. That later point may be after your `DllMain()` returns, because only one `DllMain()` can run at a time. No deadlock.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) Third, if you are deadlocking because of a `CreateThread()` in `DllMain()`, that means you are waiting for the…

Comment: ...other thread to initialize something, but that thread is waiting for its own `DllMain()` — deadlock, but not because of `CreateThread()`, but because of how your DLLs are written. Fourth, of course, this kind of thing is [why you shouldn't do anything special in `DllMain()` in the first place](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873). Last, you don't have to be injecting a DLL to use `CreateRemoteThread()`. [I certainly don't.](https://github.com/andlabs/barspy) I imagine the answer to your question has too many pitfalls to reliably exist.